# Type.GetMethod returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I was experimenting with the the Type.GetMethod method the other day when I ran into a problem.

My program is a Windows application. There is one textbox in the form used for output and there are only these two blocks of code in the Form1_Load method:

```
   MethodInfo info2 = typeof(IEnumerable<int>).GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
   textBox1.Text += info2.ToString();

   MethodInfo info1 = typeof(IEnumerator<int>).GetMethod("MoveNext");
   textBox1.Text += info1.ToString();
```

The first GetMethod returned the correct information, but the second one returned nothing.

So I went one step further and included a try/catch statement in the code:

```
        try
        {
            MethodInfo info2 = typeof(IEnumerable<int>).GetMethod("GetEnumerator");
            textBox1.Text += info2.ToString();

            MethodInfo info1 = typeof(IEnumerator<int>).GetMethod("MoveNext");
            textBox1.Text += info1.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception v)
        {
            textBox1.Text += v.Message;
        }
```

The second GetMethod now gives me the error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am confused. Neither method is static and neither takes any parameter. Why does MoveNext return the error while GetEnumerator doesn't?

Comment: When I run your code `typeof(String).GetMethod("ToString");` throws an `AmbiguousMatchException`, which makes sense because the `String` class has two overloads for the `ToString` method.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472980/how-to-instantiate-the-class-in-an-assembly-using-reflection-with-c-net

Comment: @BACON My bad. I was actually running the same test on IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator and IEnumerator<int>.MoveNext and had the two mixed up. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because the interface `IEnumerator<T>` does not have a definition for `MoveNext`, that is in the interface `IEnumerator`.

Example:

```
   MethodInfo info1 = typeof(IEnumerator).GetMethod("MoveNext");
   textBox1.Text += info1.ToString();
```

This will work fine,

You can loop though the Interfaces assigned to `IEnumerator<T>` and find `MoveNext`

```
MethodInfo info1 = typeof(IEnumerator<int>).GetInterfaces()
                  .Where(i => i.GetMethod("MoveNext") != null)
                  .Select(m => m.GetMethod("MoveNext"))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
textBox1.Text += info1 != null ? info1.ToString() : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Did you mean to say IEnumerator<T> does not have a def for MoveNext (because that's what I have). However your solution is correct. I imported System.Collections into my code and removed the <int> part and it now works.

Comment: well getting Method info for Generic Interface is a little complicated, for non generic it will be fine always!

Comment: Thanks AppDeveloper. Learn something everyday.

Comment: that is ok! but i still want to get the info for generic one!

Comment: Ahh.. yes sorry for the typos.

Comment: @Bacon, its because interfaces are not inherited, they are to be implemented. So IEnumerator<int> does not inherit IEnumerator it only implements IEnumerator.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this:

> but the second one returned nothing.

That means the second line of the second pair, it's like you were trying to do this:

```
null.ToString();
```

That's where the exception comes from, not the line above it. You can't use properties or methods of a null object like that.