# Setting Object by type C#

Tags: c#, .net

What i need to do is something like this, but really can't understand how.

```
 Object value = new typeof(i.FieldType.GetType());
```

The type of the value can be whatever, it just must be inherit of a class (for example, BaseClass). The type will be read from (.Net) System.Reflections. But i don't know how can i create a new object of this.

How can i create a new() object (constructor), of an object stored as Object, of which the type if known by the System.Reflections?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need a Factory method.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: I guess this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472980/how-to-instantiate-the-class-in-an-assembly-using-reflection-with-c-net ?

Comment: Unless you're writing something specialistic, a generic application doesn't need reflection. Using base classes, interfaces and perhaps a factory as suggested by @Robert you should be fine. Explain how you would use this code later.

Comment: `BaseClass value = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(t))`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes That will only work if he doesn't want access to the inherited class's members.

Comment: With the example above, he will be able to see the inherited members of `BaseClass`. If he needs to see the new members of `t` then he needs this: `T value = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T))`; However, `T` is  unknown at compile time, since `i.FieldType.GetType()` gets it dynamically. So the best he can do is: `BaseClass value = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(i.FieldType.GetType());`

Comment: i need to save all the parameters of any class, to string, and then load them back. So i have wrote a class which converts all types i needed, and this one will be used to convert classes as field. here there is a simplified example of what i mean: http://hastebin.com/heyoqolina.coffee

Comment: ya @OlivierJacot-Descombes, looks awesome the code you provided, i m going to write the hole code, so i can test it.

Comment: The requirement sounds awfully like (de)serialisation, which is built into the Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ConstructorInfo class

```
 var constructorInfo = typeof(myclasstype).GetConstructor();
 if (constructorInfo != null)
 {
     var myclass = constructorInfo.Invoke();
 }
```

Comment: That's probably the hard way to do it.  See Oliver's comment below the question.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to construct the type at all? If you want to convert a string to a type dynamically (according to one of your comments), then all you need is the `System.Convert.ChangeType` method.

```
object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(stringValue, i.FieldType.GetType());
```

Where the second argument to `ChangeType` is a `System.Type`.

---

The `Activator` is really only needed, if you want to create new (empty) objects dynamically. If the field types you are talking about are standard types like `string`, `int`, or `bool`, then `Convert.ChangeType` will do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)